# frontend-maven-plugin fails npm install

Tags: maven, npm, frontend-maven-plugin

I can use the command line to run `npm install` and `npm run build` on my project but when I try to use the frontend-maven-plugin it fails with the following error

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] app_name                                                          [pom]
[INFO] frontend                                                           [jar]
[INFO] backend                                                            [jar]
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------------< com.flareback-domain:app_name >----------------------
[INFO] Building app_name 1.0-SNAPSHOT                                    [1/3]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ app_name ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ app_name ---
[INFO] Installing /Users/flareback/code/app_name/pom.xml to /Users/flareback/.m2/repository/com/flareback-domain/app_name/1.0-SNAPSHOT/app_name-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------------< com.flareback-domain:frontend >----------------------
[INFO] Building frontend 1.0-SNAPSHOT                                     [2/3]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ frontend ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/flareback/code/app_name/frontend/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.9.1:install-node-and-npm (install node and npm) @ frontend ---
[INFO] Node v12.14.1 is already installed.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.9.1:npm (npm install) @ frontend ---
[INFO] Running 'npm install' in /Users/flareback/code/app_name/frontend
[INFO] internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:796
[INFO]     throw err;
[INFO]     ^
[INFO] 
[INFO] Error: Cannot find module './internal/streams/buffer_list'
[INFO] Require stack:
[INFO] - /Users/flareback/code/app_name/frontend/node/node_modules/npm/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js
[INFO] - /Users/flareback/code/app_name/frontend/node/node_modules/npm/node_modules/readable-stream/readable.js
[INFO] - /Users/flareback/code/app_name/frontend/node/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npmlog/node_modules/are-we-there-yet/tracker-stream.js
[INFO] - /Users/flareback/code/app_name/frontend/node/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npmlog/node_modules/are-we-there-yet/tracker-group.js
[INFO] - /Users/flareback/code/app_name/frontend/node/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npmlog/node_modules/are-we-there-yet/index.js
[INFO] - /Users/flareback/code/app_name/frontend/node/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npmlog/log.js
[INFO] - /Users/flareback/code/app_name/frontend/node/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
[INFO]     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:793:17)
[INFO]     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:686:27)
[INFO]     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:848:19)
[INFO]     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
[INFO]     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/flareback/code/app_name/frontend/node/node_modules/npm/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:72:18)
[INFO]     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)
[INFO]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
[INFO]     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
[INFO]     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
[INFO]     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:848:19) {
[INFO]   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
[INFO]   requireStack: [
[INFO]     '/Users/flareback/code/app_name/frontend/node/node_modules/npm/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js',
[INFO]     '/Users/flareback/code/app_name/frontend/node/node_modules/npm/node_modules/readable-stream/readable.js',
[INFO]     '/Users/flareback/code/app_name/frontend/node/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npmlog/node_modules/are-we-there-yet/tracker-stream.js',
[INFO]     '/Users/flareback/code/app_name/frontend/node/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npmlog/node_modules/are-we-there-yet/tracker-group.js',
[INFO]     '/Users/flareback/code/app_name/frontend/node/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npmlog/node_modules/are-we-there-yet/index.js',
[INFO]     '/Users/flareback/code/app_name/frontend/node/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npmlog/log.js',
[INFO]     '/Users/flareback/code/app_name/frontend/node/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js'
[INFO]   ]
[INFO] }
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for app_name 1.0-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO] 
[INFO] app_name ........................................... SUCCESS [  0.279 s]
[INFO] frontend ........................................... FAILURE [  0.438 s]
[INFO] backend ............................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.902 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-02-04T10:34:21-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.9.1:npm (npm install) on project frontend: Failed to run task: 'npm install' failed. org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :frontend
```

My frontend pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>frontend</artifactId>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>app_name</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.flareback-domain</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <frontend-maven-plugin.version>1.9.1</frontend-maven-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${frontend-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install node and npm</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <nodeVersion>v12.14.1</nodeVersion>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>install</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm run build</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>run build</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 7):

I added node and npm version same as my local machine version then this error disappered

```
 <properties>
       <frontend-maven-plugin.version>1.6</frontend-maven-plugin.version>
       <node.version>v12.18.1</node.version>
       <npm.version>6.14.5</npm.version>
  </properties>
```

Comment: It's the best answer. I have tried all possible cases and recommendations. People write to change the version to a specific one or / and remove node_modules etc. But it only helped to install the version to the current one. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

I changed my pom to use a different node version

`<nodeVersion>v9.11.1</nodeVersion>`

I then ran `mvn clean install`. That failed but it got past the install part and failed on the run build. Then I switched back to `<nodeVersion>v12.14.1</nodeVersion>` and re-ran the `mvn clean install` and it worked.

Comment: Great! after changing node to v9.11.1 it works. I think it was not compatible on higher version. Thank @flareback

Answer (score 1):

I have this error but my issue is that I added "v" before npm version.
If you get node version, node --version you'll get "v12.3.4" but if you get npm version, you 'll get "5.4.3".
In pom file,

```
<properties>
    <node.version>v16.13.0</node.version>
    <npm.version>8.1.0</npm.version>    <java.version>11</java.version>

</properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's node version issue. Also possible that your global node version mismatches.

I have implemented following code with node version 10.16.0

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <nodeVersion>v10.16.0</nodeVersion>
                <npmVersion>6.10.2</npmVersion>
                <workingDirectory>./angular</workingDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
            
                <execution>
                    <id>install node and npm</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                </execution>
        
        
                <execution>
                        <id>npm install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>install</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                </execution> 
        
    
                <execution>
                    <id>npm run-script build</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>run-script build</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

If this still not work, try clearing npm cache with force attribute

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: This code basically installs a  node package with local scope only for your Project and ignores system node version

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Turn out I just had forgotten to add the 'v' in my node version.

Answer (score 0):

change node version and npm version in the pom file to the node and npm versions that are installed in your local machine. Then run a mvn clean install. It will solve your issue.
This is how i did it.

(1) This is the node and npm versions that are in the project earlier
node - v10.15.2
npm - 6.4.1

(2)This is after i changed the versions
node - v14.19.1
npm - 6.14.16

(3)Then run mvn clean install.

Your problem sould be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Set the node version same as you have on your local machine. You can find the local version with help of

```
npm -v
```

and

```
node --version
```

My understanding says that whatever environment argument you are using should already be working for your local. In my case "--openssl-legacy-provider is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS" was the issue. So, if you switch the version of node and npm in 'frontend-maven-plugin', it should basically allow you to use your local installed versions.
Finally updated version matching to my local.

```
<execution>
    <id>install node and npm</id>
    <goals>
        <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <nodeVersion>v20.4.0</nodeVersion>
        <npmVersion>9.7.2</npmVersion>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

Answer (score -1):

I upgraded the Node LTS version and now it works.